# How to open CSV with multiple values in each row and store it in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm new to python and trying to do the following:

Open a CSV file with 5 different values separated by comma.

I want to store the data in a dictionary which key will be `row[0]`.

Suppose there are 4 rows so 4 primary keys, for each key I need to create another nested dictionary with 4 new keys, each key with the values of rows 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Let's say the CSV contains:

```
1,hi,1,2,3
2,yes,2,3,4
3,no,3,4,5
4,why,4,5,6
```

and I need to store:

`dict={'1': { 'key2':hi,'key3':1,'key4':2,'key5':3}, '2':{ }, '3':{}, '4':{} }`

This is the code I'm using

```
import csv
dict={}
    reader = csv.reader(open('filename.csv', 'r'))
    for row in reader:
        key=row[0]
        for key in dict:
           dict[key]={}
           dict[key][key2]=row[1]
           dict[key][key3]=row[2]
           dict[key][key4]=row[3]
           dict[key][key5]=row[4]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are the values of the keys '2', '3' and '4' in your example empty?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work is because for each `row` you are iterating over keys of an empty dictionary `for key in dict` resulting in no actions being taken.

Instead, if you would like to insert `{'key2': row[1], 'key3': row[2], 'key4': row[3], 'key5': row[4]}` to `dict[row[0]]` try the following. Also, avoid using variables named after builtin types, i.e. `list`, `set`, `all`, `dict`.

```
import csv
output_dict = {}
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as f:    
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
      output_dict[row[0]] = {'key%d' % (i + 1): row[i] for i in xrange(1, 5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that does what you are asking:

```
import csv
my_dictionary = {}
reader = csv.reader(open('filename.csv', 'r'))
for row in reader:
    my_dictionary[row[0]] = {}
    for index in range(1, len(row)):
        my_dictionary[row[0]]['key' + str(index)] = row[index]
```

You should avoid naming a dictionary 'dict' because that is the name of the function that creates dictionary objects. Also, the variable 'key' gets overwritten by your iterator variable.